# Not getting Updated TIFF Data of UIImage using ImageIO Framework

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am using **ImageIO framework** for updating metadata of UIImage then after I saved that image in my iphone photoLibrary my issue is that I am updating the Image TIFF data successfully in image but when I select that image for get TIFF data then it not displaying the TIFF dictionary data .online I can see updated TIFF data but in my code i can't see it.

**Updated TIFF Data:**

```
"{TIFF}" =     {
        Make = "test ";
        Model = test;
        Software = test;
    };
```

**[image: online check TIFF data :-]**

**Get updated Image metadata in iOS:**

```
{
    ColorModel = RGB;
    Depth = 8;
    PixelHeight = 2592;
    PixelWidth = 1936;
    "{PNG}" =     {
        InterlaceType = 0;
    };
}
```

**Code:**

```
 NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
     CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef )imageData, NULL);
    if (imageSource == NULL) {
            // Error loading image
            return nil;
        }

    //Set the object in dictinary

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], (NSString *)kCGImageSourceShouldCache,
                             nil];
    CFDictionaryRef imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options);

//Device name

    CFDictionaryRef refDeviceInfo = CFDictionaryGetValue(imageProperties, kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary);
    if (refDeviceInfo) {

        NSString *strMake = (NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(refDeviceInfo, kCGImagePropertyTIFFMake);
        NSLog(@"Make: %@", strMake);

        NSString *strModel = (NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(refDeviceInfo, kCGImagePropertyTIFFModel);
       NSLog(@"Model: %@", strModel);
  }
```

Comment: so what is the output ?? are u fetching the image again from the library after updating it ??

Comment: yes i am fetching updated metadat image from library

Comment: ur retrieval code looks ok .. So wat was the value u updated with .. and what are the values u are getting. check and see ur updation code properly.

Comment: i m updating the model,make and software for image its update successfully but when i retrive that updated metadata then it not give me